# Is there a way to create a "default" method for a Python class that is used by all inherited classes automatically?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, methods

(PYTHON 3.x) I want to have a method in the parent class that is ran each time a class is constructed in any subsequent classes inheriting from the parent. Thanks for the help.

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name: str, salary: float, years: int):
        self.w_name = name
        self.w_salary = salary
        self.w_years = years
        self.pension_amt = .1

    def pension(self):
        return self.w_years * (self.w_salary * self.pension_amt)
```

Comment: [`__init_subclass__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)?

Comment: Can you please explain precisely what the behavior is you are seeking? What does "ran each time a class is constructed in any subsequent classes inheriting from the parent. " mean *exactly*?

Comment: Your `__init__()` method sounds promising.

Comment: Thank you all, that was the right was to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Add it to `__init__`. For example,

```
class Worker:
    def __init__(self, name: str, salary: float, years: int):
        self.w_name = name
        self.w_salary = salary
        self.w_years = years
        self.pension_amt = .1
        self.pension = self.pension()
```

Then, any child class defined as

```
class Child(Worker):
   def __init__(self, name, salary, years):                                                                                                                                                          
       super().__init__(name, salary, years)
```

will run it.